# BonCode Connector, IIS 7.5 & Tomcat 8, slow & intermittent Request timed out errors

Tags: iis-7.5, tomcat8

I have a JSP web-app hosted on IIS 7.5 & Tomcat 8.0.30 via BonCode AJP13 v1.0.26 on Win 2008 R2 64 bit.

This has been working OK for a few months to date.

We have identical environments: development, staging & production.

On the development and staging environments, suddenly, we are getting very slow responses and in some cases, intermittent IIS generated timeout errors:

```
Request timed out
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.
[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]
```

On the production environment, performance seems OK.

Tried re-booting servers, restarting IIS, restarting Tomcat etc

Has anyone had these slow-downs?

Does anyone use a known working version of BonCode greater than 1.0.26?

**Details**

Bypassing IIS & BonCode, ie explicity selecting port 8080, gives an instant response.

```
http://<domain>:8080/<path>
```

The slowdown is not JSP page specific.
Even very simple pages, eg get date & time, still intermittently gives slow responses.

There is no authentication on Tomcat / JSP web-app.

A single instance of Tomcat residing on the same server as IIS 7.5
ie no load-balancing etc.

Only plain HTTP is being used
ie not HTTPS and no associated certificates.

**Server Diagnosis**

- BonCode logs

Occasionally, this is seen:

```
2016-02-29 15:59:01 1.0.26 ERROR 
TCP Client level -- Server/Port:localhost/8009
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: buffer
2016-02-29 15:59:01 One Connection raised an error
```

but usually, no related errors / warnings are being shown

Comparing with older logs

Old log

```
2017-05-04 10:19:28 New Connection 46 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 46 [T-5]
2017-05-04 10:19:35 New Connection 47 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 47 [T-45]
2017-05-04 10:25:11 New Connection 48 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 48 [T-45]
2017-05-04 10:25:15 New Connection 49 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 49 [T-49]
2017-05-04 10:39:12 New Connection 50 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 50 [T-49]
2017-05-04 10:40:09 New Connection 51 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 51 [T-22]
2017-05-04 10:41:29 New Connection 52 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 52 [T-49]
2017-05-04 10:42:03 New Connection 53 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 53 [T-52]
2017-05-04 11:05:04 New Connection 1 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 1 [T-20]
2017-05-04 11:06:37 New Connection 2 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 2 [T-23]
2017-05-04 11:07:23 New Connection 3 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 3 [T-51]
2017-05-04 11:08:55 New Connection 4 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 4 [T-23]
2017-05-04 11:09:17 New Connection 5 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 5 [T-51]
```

New log

```
2017-05-16 14:31:57 New Connection 200 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 200 [T-153]
2017-05-16 14:31:58 New Connection 201 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 201 [T-153]
2017-05-16 14:32:30 New Connection 202 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 202 [T-153]
2017-05-16 14:36:05 New Connection 204 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 204 [T-153]
2017-05-16 14:36:06 New Connection 205 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 205 [T-153]
2017-05-16 14:41:38 New Connection 206 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 206 [T-153]
2017-05-16 14:42:51 New Connection 207 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 207 [T-153]
2017-05-16 14:42:52 New Connection 208 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 208 [T-153]
2017-05-16 14:43:12 New Connection 209 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 209 [T-153]
2017-05-16 14:43:40 New Connection 210 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 210 [T-153]
```

In the old log, the connection ids seem to reset after ~20-80 with each connection using a range of threads, occasionally the same thread.

In the new log, with the slow down, the connection ids are far higher and seem to be using the same thread.

- Tomcat logs

no errors, as expected as servlet/JSP requests are not being forwarded.

**Configuration Files**

BonCode - BonCodeAJP13.settings

```
<Settings>
   <Port>8009</Port>
   <Server>localhost</Server>   
   <MaxConnections>0</MaxConnections>
   <LogLevel>2</LogLevel>
   <LogDir>E:\inetpub\logs\BonCode</LogDir>
   <FlushThreshold>0</FlushThreshold>
   <EnableRemoteAdmin>False</EnableRemoteAdmin>
   <HeaderBlacklist>AUTHORIZATION,URL,SERVER_SOFTWARE,SERVER_NAME,SERVER_PROTOCOL</HeaderBlacklist>
   <PacketSize>65536</PacketSize>
</Settings>
```

Tomcat - server.xml

```
...
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" 
           packetSize="65536" />
...
```

**Notes**

I am aware that BonCode v1.0.26 has now been updated to v1.0.36, but the newer version has only been out for about 10 days.

If I do not get anywhere, I will upgrade but there are limits to what I can do on the production environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long term: plan for upgrade. You are back 10 versions.

Most likely you are exhausting the number of AJP connections. 
I would adjust the Tomcat connection and timeout parameters to remove stuck connections:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" keepAliveTimeout="-1" connectionTimeout="60000" maxThreads="1000" packetSize="65536" />
```

Best,
Brian

Comment: Thanks Brian, For Tomcat, if maxThreads is not specified, it defaults to 200. A setting of 1000 seems too high for this - this is a low traffic site. Also, this Tomcat change needs a corresponding BonCode change as BonCode MaxConnections = Tomcat maxThreads. As you say, some limit is being reached - I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Tomcat, if maxThreads is not specified, it defaults to 200. 
[Tomcat 8 docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html)

For BonCode, if MaxConnections = 0, connection pooling is not used but BonCode will create a new connection for each request.

From the BonCode source code:

```
...
p_Logger.LogMessage(String.Format("New Connection {0} of {1} to tomcat: {2} ID: {3} [T-{4}]", p_ConcurrentConnections, BonCodeAJP13Settings.MAX_BONCODEAJP13_CONCURRENT_CONNECTIONS, p_TCPClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), p_ThisConnectionID, AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()), BonCodeAJP13LogLevels.BONCODEAJP13_LOG_BASIC);
...
```

From this, I would expect the BonCode connection id to reach & peak at 200.

Also, AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()) is deprecated and should not be relied on to give the thread-id.

Looking at more BonCode logs:

```
2017-05-16 15:44:27 New Connection 190 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 190 [T-153]
2017-05-16 15:44:28 New Connection 192 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 192 [T-153]
2017-05-16 15:44:29 New Connection 194 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 194 [T-153]
2017-05-16 15:44:43 New Connection 196 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 196 [T-153]
2017-05-16 15:44:44 New Connection 198 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 198 [T-153]
2017-05-16 15:45:08 New Connection 200 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 200 [T-153]
2017-05-16 15:45:30 New Connection 201 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 201 [T-153]
2017-05-16 15:46:58 New Connection 203 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 203 [T-153]
2017-05-16 15:48:47 New Connection 204 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 204 [T-153]
2017-05-16 15:49:16 New Connection 205 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 205 [T-153]
2017-05-16 15:53:54 One Connection raised an error
2017-05-16 15:59:56 New Connection 206 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 206 [T-152]
2017-05-16 15:59:57 New Connection 207 of 0 to tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8009 ID: 207 [T-152]
2017-05-16 16:05:37 One Connection raised an error
```

Not sure why the error was not raised at connection 201 but it looks like BonCode connections are being exhausted, not being closed and / or Tomcat max thread count is being reached.

Will upgrade to v1.0.36 and see what happens

Comment: So Kevin, what was the ultimate solution?

Comment: @Charlie - upgraded to BonCode v1.0.36 and used the configuration in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769767/boncode-connector-iis-7-5-tomcat-8-intermittent-generic-connector-error/37542282#37542282)